# Required help in removing the column from text file using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a sample file like this . Using data factory Where I need to create another text file with output where I can remove the 1st two columns. Is there any query where I can generate a file like as below.

Source file:

[image]

Output file :

[image]

Comment: Data flow is the right tool for this. After loading the source, use SELECT to capture only the columns you want, then the SINK will output only the selected columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data Factory (ie not including Mapping Data Flows) is not gifted with many abilities to do data transformation (which this is) however it can do some things.  It can change formats (eg .csv to JSON), it can add some metadata columns (like $$FILENAME) and it can remove columns, simply by using the mapping in the Copy activity.

1. Add a Copy activity to your pipeline and set the source to your main file
2. Set the Sink to your target file name.  It can be the same name as your original file but I would make it different for audit trail purposes.
3. Import the schema of your file, make sure the separator in the dataset is set to semi-colon ';'

[image: Import schema]
4. Now press the Trash can button to delete the mappings for columns 1 and 2.
5. Run your pipeline.  The output file should not have the two columns.

My results:

[image: My results]

Comment: Please upvote if this answer was useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task by using **[Select transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-select)** in Azure Data Factory (ADF). You can delete any unwanted columns from your delimited text file in data flow transformation.

I tested the same in my environment and it is working fine.

Please follow the below steps:

1. Create the Azure Data factory using Azure Portal
2. Upload the data at the source (eg: Blob Container)
3. Create a linked service to connect the blob storage with ADF as shown below

[image]

4. Then, create **DelimitedText** datasets using the above linked service for source and sink files. In the source dataset, mark **Column delimiter** as **Semicolon(;)**. Also, in the **Schema** tab, select **Import Schema From connection/store**.

[image]

[image]

5. Create a data flow. Select the Source dataset from your datasets list. Click on **+** symbol to add **Select** from options as shown below.

[image]

6. **In the settings, select the columns you want to delete and then click on delete option.

[image]

7. Add the sink at the end. In the **Sink** tab use the sink dataset you created earlier in step 4. In the **Settings** tab, for **File name option** select **Output to single file** and give the filename in below option.
8. Now create a pipeline and use the Data flow activity. Select the data flow you created. Click on Trigger Now option to run the pipeline.

Check the output file at the sink location. You can see my input and output files below.

[image]